# Alternative for Under the Guidance of

Tags: grammar, phrases, expressions

I am writing a statement of purpose and want an alternative for "under the guidance of Professor". I has been used many times in the SOP and I want to avoid using it as much as possible. One alternative I can think of it "worked for Professor ..." but I do not know if that is correct (Objection I have: I think university is the employer and not the professor).

Please let me know how this can be rephrased or alternatives for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"in collaboration with Professor Jones."*

Comment: "under the aegis of"

Comment: It might help to describe more about what you were doing "under the guidance of Professor." Were you interning, working a regular job, receiving special training, or being guided in some other way?

Comment: I **guess** you're writing something about how you will carry out work/study for a higher degree. This is bordering on writing advice, but please give full details including a couple of example sentences.

Comment: "to work with" is certainly used in academia. You could also replace guidance with supervision, depending on what exactly his/her role was.

Comment: I'm really surprised nobody has said "Mentorship" yet. It means "guidance by a more learned person" but implies a higher degree of knowledge on your part than "tutelage" would.

Answer (score 1):

with assistance from Prof...
assisted by Prof...
supervised by Prof...
sponsored by Prof...
under the office of Prof...

Comment: Also "under the lead/leadership/supervision/tutorship/umbrella/direction of Professor X", "I assisted/seconded Professor X", "I contributed/participated to Professor X research works/papers".

Answer (score 0):

[**Tutelage**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tutelage)


**tu·te·lage** 
ˈt(y)o͞odlij/noun
protection of or authority over someone or something; **guardianship**.

```
Please let me know how this can be rephrased or alternatives for this.
```

"**under the *tutelage* of Professor**" ...

instruction; tuition.

"**he felt honored to be under the *tutelage* of an experienced professor**"